# How to replace null values using orderBy in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I properly replace null values with different values like a string using `orderby` in lodash.

Currently this is what I am doing to replace null values with a string. I will use a separate `foreach loop` to replace the null values for `.GroupDate`  with a string and then use the `orderBy` function.

```
test.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (e.GroupDate === null) {
      test[i].GroupDate = i.toString();
    }
});

test = orderBy(test, [c => c.GroupDate, c => c.Index, c => c.Date], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

If there a better way to replace the foreach loop and add this condition inside the `orderBy` ?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
let groupDateNumber = 0;

test = orderBy(test, [
    (c) => {
      if (c.GroupDate === null) {
        c.GroupDate = groupDateNumber.toString();
      }
      groupDateNumber++;
      return c.GroupDate, c => c.Index, c => c.Timestamp;
    }
], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing your objects as you're sorting them. It's not really an optimisation, as sorting algorithms tend to run in `O(n * log n)`  best case scenario with some going for `O(n^2)` but they might be better for lower amount of input. So, at the very least, you'd be checking each element more than once (`n * log n` on the lower estimate on average). A simple `forEach` is 1. cleaner to read 2. easier to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iteratee function is returning an array is that correct? I believe what you want is

```js
let groupDateNumber = 0;

test = orderBy(test, [
    (c) => {
      if (c.GroupDate === null) {
        c.GroupDate = groupDateNumber.toString();
      }
      groupDateNumber++;
      return c.GroupDate;
    },
    c => c.Index,
    c => c.Timestamp
], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

Another way you could do this through use of lodash seq method `_(value)` and `map` and `orderBy`. This should use lazy evaluation so it should be efficient, although I'm not sure how well chaining works with orderBy and sortBy.

```js
test = _(test)
  .map((e, i) => {
    if (e.GroupDate === null) {
      e.GroupDate = i.toString();
    }
    return e;
  })
  .orderBy([c => c.GroupDate, c => c.Index, c => c.Date], ['desc', 'asc'])
  .value()
```

Comment: If you're going to be directly mutating the elements, I suggest using `.each`/`.forEach`. It still returns everything that passes through but it's more clear in the intent. `.map` typically doesn't do mutations.

Comment: Yeah good point, but I thought from looking at lodash documentation that forEach/each is not wrappable

Comment: I haven't checked but it should be, as far as I remember. I do recall being surprised it actually worked when I saw it somewhere else. EDIT: apparently I misremember. `.forEach` is indeed not chainable. Not sure what I saw before that surprised me, then.

Comment: I just tried in a node console `_([{ a: 1, b:2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]).forEach(el => el.a += 1).orderBy([c => c.a, c => c.b], ['asc', 'desc']).value()` but got an error "is not a function". Was using lodash "4.17.20"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function array as second parameter and check for null values:

```
const textIfNull = '';

test = orderBy(test, [c => c.GroupDate || textIfNull, c => c.Index, c => c.Date], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-breeze-14rb3?file=/src/index.js) with an example for you.